# Setting bounds and making map bounce back if moved away

Tags: leaflet, extents

I want to make this map bounce to the center, and make the red line the limit that you can move the map.

Don't know why my fitbounds doesn't work.

Any help?

My code:

```
var mapBounds = L.latLngBounds([
                    [-8576 / 2, -8576 / 2],
                    [8576 / 2, 8576 / 2]
                ]);
                map.fitBounds(mapBounds);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/XQxgpcYjiVaUhU4jCQV9?p=preview

I want something similar to this example:

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/maxbounds/

You can't move away from that part.

Comment: An obvious but possibly unforeseen effect of MaxBounds-type things is that users can't scroll to markers near the boundary: Say your northernmost location, the marker/icon will fall off the map when zoomed in from initial level; and you can't center your map around it (e.g. for screenshot). So ideally, you'd insert some extra space (say +1degree for N/E corner and -1degree for S/W corner).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**[Final Answer]**

I bet you can easily resolve this by setting the map's [`maxBounds`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-options) equal to its initial bounds immediately upon loading. :)

Just add this to your initializing code once your map variable is ready.

```
map.setMaxBounds(map.getBounds());
```

---

**[Original Response]**

When you instantiate your Leaflet map, you just need to pass in a [`maxBounds`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-options) option among your map options.

> When this option is set, the map restricts the view to the given
>   geographical bounds, bouncing the user back when he tries to pan
>   outside the view. To set the restriction dynamically, use setMaxBounds
>   method.

Looking at the Mapbox example you provided, modified a bit, that happens like this:

```
// Create the LatLngBounds object like this..
// 
var southWest = L.latLng(40.712, -74.227),
    northEast = L.latLng(40.774, -74.125),
    bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

var map = L.map('map', {
    maxBounds: bounds,   // Then add it here..
    maxZoom: 19,
    minZoom: 10
});
```

---

**[Follow-up to comments]**

With respect to the custom coordinate system in use here, it might be useful to add something like this toward the end of your initialization code to get the *current* `LatLngBounds` values for your map right after it has loaded:

`console.log(map.getBounds().toString());`

Hopefully then, the console output will yield some clues as to how the coordinates should look. If that doesn't work, you can get more specific, like this:

`console.log(map.getBounds().getSouthWest().toString());`
`console.log(map.getBounds().getNorthEast().toString());`

Which I expect will show exactly how those southwest and northeast coordinates look after the map is initialized, and they have been normalized for your leaflet map.

Finally, [it might help to look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718223/leaflet-maxbounds-with-custom-projection) for a little more discussion on handling the `LatLngBounds` object within a custom coordinate system.

Comment: But how do I achieve that bounds with my custom coordinates? That's the problem.

Comment: @RogerHN, hmm gotcha ..well, how are you actually initializing your map with your custom coordinates? It might help to see that. Also check out [this post on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718223/leaflet-maxbounds-with-custom-projection) that discusses `maxBounds` with respect to custom coordinate systems.

Comment: @RogerHN, if I were in your shoes, I'd add something like this toward the end of your initialization code to get the current extend of your map *right after* it has loaded: `console.log(map.getBounds().toString);` Hopefully then, the console output might give you a clue as to how that object should look. You can also get very specific, like `console.log(map.getBounds().getSouthWest().toString);`, which will show you just that southwest coordinate.. and `.getNorthEast()`, respectively. If you can just see them once, then you should know how to proceed.

Comment: This is what I get using console.log(map.getBounds().toString);:
`function toString() { [native code] }`

And using console.log(map.getBounds().getSouthWest().toString); :

`function (t){return"LatLng("+o.Util.formatNum(this.lat,t)+", "+o.Util.formatNum(this.lng,t)+")"}`

Comment: @RogerHN, note the two parens following `.toString()` ..it looks like you're missing them, which is why it's returning the function definition rather than executing the function and returning the result.

Comment: @RogerHN, something just occurred to me--I bet you can just set the `maxBounds` equal to the current bounds like this: `map.setMaxBounds(map.getBounds());`

Comment: This solved my months-long problem too. But is there a way to set the maxBoundsViscosity to be 1.0 so that when the map is dragged, it DOESN'T pan outside the bounds then bounce back to the center. I want the maxBounds to be rigid so that it doesn't have to load some additional tiles outside the bounds.

Comment: @JAT86, it sounds like your answered your own question...as the `maxBoundsViscosity` value of 1 should make the map very restrictive. However, you'll need to establish this value as a mapOption parameter when you instantiate your map. See [this answer over at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31529463/786131) for an example of this..